# Blazor - get the Identity.Id in a service

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to get the IdentityUser.Id in a service?

The AuthenticationStateTask has it as `(await AuthenticationStateTask).User.Claims` has a claim with the guid that's the IdentityUser.Id. But I don't see any way to get that in a service.

A service can get the AuthenticationStateProvider. But [that does not track state data change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service).

But all I need is that guid. That will not change - correct? In which case I can use the AuthenticationStateProvider object.

For those that are interested, I need this for two things. First I am creating an ILogger for each razor page where that id is a scope for each log message. Makes it easy to get log messages for a user.

Second, for each primary Entity Framework model, I write the ID to each object when it is created/updated. That provides a really good audit trail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `AuthenticationStateProvider` into your service and register for the `AuthenticationStateChanged` event.

The `AuthenticationStateChangedHandler` returns a `Task<AuthenticationState>` from which you can get the Id.

It's how `CascadingAuthenticationState` works.

Here's the code from the DotNet Repository for reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Authorization/src/CascadingAuthenticationState.razor

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<CascadingValue TValue="System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AuthenticationState>" Value="@_currentAuthenticationStateTask" ChildContent="@ChildContent" />

@code {
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? _currentAuthenticationStateTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// The content to which the authentication state should be provided.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;

        _currentAuthenticationStateTask = AuthenticationStateProvider
            .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    }

    private void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> newAuthStateTask)
    {
        _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            _currentAuthenticationStateTask = newAuthStateTask;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: David - The [AspNetCore Github Repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/) is a rich store of information on how to do things.  I use it a lot to see how MS implements stuff.